# Как заставить replaceWith отрабатывать несколько раз

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня на странице есть окно поиска куда пользователь может ввести символ и ему показываеться список всех найденных совпадений. Проблема заключаеться в том, что когда пользователь продолжает вводить символы, список не обновляется. Получаеться он срабатывает один раз.

```
 $("#search").keyup(function () {
            var input = $('#search').val().toLowerCase();//User input

            var filteredList = array.filter(el => el.indexOf(input) > -1);//Check for matches
            var string = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < filteredList.length; i++)
            {
                newString += "<li>" + filteredList[i] + "</li>";
            }
            $("#userlist").replaceWith(newString );
        });
```

Comment: вам вероятно внутренности заменить надо  - `$("#userlist").html(newString)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как заставить replaceWith отрабатывать несколько раз

Никак не заставлять, это не та функция, что вам необходима. `replaceWith` заменяет сам элемент (`<ul id="userlist">`), вам же, судя по всему, требуется заменить только вложенные пункты. Для этих целей используется `$("#userlist").html(newString)`.

Хотя, конечно, можно работать и с `replaceWith`. Полученную строку нужно обернуть в тэг `<ul>`: `newString = "<ul id="userlist"> + newString + "</ul>"`, но это нелогично.

Comment: Огромное спасибо.